# Issue with Plots in R

Tags: r, plot

Data:
I have a dataframe with 2 columns

```
Col1 20160628 20160629 20160630 20160701 20160702
Col2 500      600      700      800      900
```

I need Col1 in x axis and Col2 to be y axis

When I am using plot to make the graph, on the x axis its showing the data points like 20160680 and so on, which is very misleading on the graph.

I juts need this 5 points on the graph equally spaced.

Comment: does converting your col1 to a factor help achieve what you want?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I though I could mark 2 answers!!!!, yours was the one which worked for me first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An obvious thing you can try is:

```
x <- c(20160628,20160629,20160630,20160701,20160702)
y <- 5:9 * 100

x <- as.character(as.Date(as.character(x),format = "%Y%m%d")) ## convert to date
# [1] "2016-06-28" "2016-06-29" "2016-06-30" "2016-07-01" "2016-07-02"
plot(y, xaxt = "n", xlab = "Date")  ## do not draw x-axis
axis(1, at = 1:length(y), labels = x)  ## add x-axis, using date as axis labels
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like the right way to go. If you're plotting date data, don't assume they're equally spaced, and use the actual date.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have it as a data frame, you can use ggplot2 for plotting.

```
x <- c(20160628,20160629,20160630,20160701,20160702)
y <- 5:9 * 100
x <- as.character(as.Date(as.character(x),format = "%Y%m%d"))
data <- data.frame(x,y)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(x="Date",y="Value")
```

[image]